# Variable $r$ in Dirac equation

Tags: general-relativity, dirac-equation

Solutions of Dirac equation for an electron in orbit of an atom are usually expressed in terms of spherical coordinates $r,\theta$ and $\phi$. For a point ($r,\theta,\phi$) the variable $r$ represents the distance from the center of the nucleus. My question is whether this is proper distance or coordinate distance? It may not make a difference in flat space-time but in presence of a gravitational field these two distances may be different. Please quote some reference if possible as I could not find anything mentioned explicitly in literature.

Comment: The Dirac equation was formulated to be consistent with Special Relativity, not GR. The only way a gravitational field could have an important effect on the solution is if there are tidal forces on the scale of the electron orbitals; how extreme of a situation are you willing to consider?

Comment: @Spencer Dirac equation in GR is a vast field in itself with real implications at atomic level. Search for it and you will find amazing stuff.